# plupload file not available / not found

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload, plupload

I use the pluploader and jquery for file uploads. 
I still search a solution for this Problem:

After adding a file the user renames this file on the harddisk.
In IE the request is send anyway with an empty file content. (this is ok for me)
But in FF (V11) the request never seems to end.

Unfortunately the `"Error"` trigger doesn't work.
In `"UploadFile"` and `"BeforeUpload"` I queried `file.status` but it's only "2" ("uploading") and not "failed".

Does anybody have an idea how to stop the request, or how to check if the file is still available ?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with plupload as far as I knew that's not possible.Once when the user finishes uploading he can do whatever he needs.Before uploading or while uploading you can check the `filenames` and find the `duplicates` for them whether they exist or not.

**UPDATE:**

There is only one way you an do this.

Check for the duplicate filenames which are uploaded.For that you need to do this

```
uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
        var i = 0;
        while (i++ < up.files.length) {
            var ii = i;
            while (ii < up.files.length) {
                if (up.files[i - 1].name == up.files[ii].name) {
                    uploader.removeFile(up.files[ii]);    
                } else {
                    ii++;
                }
            }
        }
});
```

As soon as you select files if there is a file with the same filename it deletes the uploaded file and contnues with the next one and so on.

Comment: Can you explain how to do this checkup before the upload ?
You surely have to parse the files array. But how to access the harddisk to compare the filenames ?!

Comment: or is there something like a timeout option for plupload ? Because my main problem is that the request in FF never ends.

Comment: @Daniel-Updated my answer for checking duplicate filenames and there is no timeout options or so for this and I have implemented the best way so far and you can check the above code.